# jQuery pulsate background animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i can not discover why my added code to the exist plugin not works.
I've added the functionality to animate the background on the target, but it doesn't work.

this is the function that i have added into the plugin.

```
    var pulseBackground = function(options, el) {
    console.log('anim::logger');
    $(el).animate(
            {
                backgroundColor: options.animFixedBackgroundColor
            },
    {
        duration: options.duration / 2,
        complete: function() {
            el.animtimer = setTimeout(function() {
                $(el).animate({backgroundColor: $(el).css("background-color")}, {
                    duration: options.duration / 2,
                    complete: function() {
                        el.animtimer = setTimeout(pulseBackground(options, el), options.interval);
                    }
                });
            }, options.returnDelay);
        }
    }
    );

    var innerfunc = function() {
        pulseBackground(options, el);
    };

    if (el.animtimer) {
        clearTimeout(el.animtimer);
    }

    el.animtimer = setTimeout(innerfunc, options.interval);
};
```

What was my mistake, any suggestions ?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/C9X4J/

Regards Sascha

Comment: What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: The animation change from css input background to animFixedBackgroundColor: "#00ADEF" doesnt work

Comment: you need to save the background-color before the animation of animFixedBackgroundColor like this [http://jsfiddle.net/C9X4J/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/C9X4J/1/)

Comment: thanks for your help but it doesnt work the background doesnt change.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what was wrong with yours, but [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/zcEKR/1/).